# XDocument saving without line breaks

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I am using XDocument to write to an XML file. After writing is complete, the XML is not human readable as line breaks are almost entirely omitted.

```
XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
XElement xmlRoot = new XElement("root", "root");
XElement xmlEntry = new XElement("file",
   new XAttribute("name", "Example"),
   new XAttribute("hashcode", "Hashcode Example")
);
xmlRoot.Add(xmlEntry);
xmlDoc.Add(xmlRoot);
xmlDoc.Save("C:\\contents.xml");
```

I have tried various options for the xmlDoc.Save() line, including:

```
xmlDoc.Save("...", SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
xmlDoc.Save("...", SaveOptions.None);
```

Please note that code I have submitted is a reduced form from what my program actually contains; functionally it is the same.

Comment: Please clarify if your goal is to save not-formatted/non-indented XML or it is problem you face any you need nicely formatted XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above that just calls `xmlDoc.Save("C:\\contents.xml")` is saving the xml in a 'pretty' format. it just isn't formatting it the way you would expect. i think the problem is because you're adding a text value and a child node to the same node, so the parser probably doesn't know how or specifically doesn't break up those values.

if you modify your code to generate the 'root' element with no text value, it will display the xml the way you are probably expecting. i tested with this code:

```
        XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
        XElement xmlRoot = new XElement("root");
        XElement xmlEntry = new XElement("file",
           new XAttribute("name", "Example"),
           new XAttribute("hashcode", "Hashcode Example with some long string")
        );
        xmlRoot.Add(xmlEntry);
        xmlDoc.Add(xmlRoot);
        xmlDoc.Save("temp.xml");
        Console.WriteLine(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("temp.xml"));
```

a more terse way of generating the above content can be used with this code, which i find more readable as well:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
xmlDoc.Add(
    new XElement("root",
        new XElement("file",
            new XAttribute("name", "example"),
            new XAttribute("hashcode", "hashcode example")
        )
    )
);
xmlDoc.Save("temp.xml");
Console.WriteLine(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("temp.xml"));
```